# Build logic on Reversal record flag for a particular table

Tags: sql-server, mysql, postgresql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

I have Reversal flag (RF) values as ' ' , 'R' , 'D' which make the records distinct. I am selecting many columns from this table as it is a primary table and taking sum of few columns as well. There are records with all three values or just 'D' or 'R' values as well. I want to build a logic where when there is 'D' record, the corresponding 'R' record (if it exists) for the same customer id and same job(primary keys):

1. the 'D' record should be eliminated (not considered)
2. group ' ' and 'R' records into one distinct record

For example we have these records for one customer (different jobs and RF values):

| CustID | jobid | RF | GM% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1029 | 30 |  | 29 |
| 1029 | 30 | R | 29 |
| 1029 | 30 | D | 0 |
| 1029 | 38 | D | 32 |
| 1029 | 39 |  | 24 |

The result should be as:

| CustID | jobid | RF | GM% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1029 | 30 | R | 29 |
| 1029 | 38 | D | 32 |
| 1029 | 39 |  | 24 |

The Record for jobid 30 is given RF value as R but it should be grouped with the ' ' record when we have all three RF value (' ', 'R', 'D') and the record when RF value is 'D' is removed.

Where there are only 'D' values or ' ' values or only 'R' values (Distinct, with no corresponding customer and job values) then keep it as it is.

Comment: You tagged your question with multiple DBMSes; do you really need the answer for all of them? Also, please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: What if there's a different value for the `GM%` column between the row with the `R` value and the row with the `''` value?...which `GM%` value would you want shown?

Comment: there wont be any values other than those. ' '  and 'R' will have similar values. and if there is any row in between then it wud be 'D' record.

Answer (score 0):

(This Answer is probably DBMS-agnostic.)

I like the pattern of maintaining two tables:

- `history`, which is like your first one -- it contains all the details
- `current`, which is like the other table, containing only the *current* state of each Cust+Job.

This works well for "accounts" where there is a lot of activity (in `history`, but exactly one with the "current" balance.  I'm not sure if it works well for your case.

By "maintain", I mean there is code (in the app or in a Stored Procedure) that is used for each new entry -- it does both an `INSERT` into `history` and `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ...` (upsert) on the `current` table.